# Insert function in a cell if another cell changes value

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Assumption1Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If Target.Text = "D10" Then
    Range("B10").Formula = "=Now()"
    Else
    End If

    Applicatoin.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am using the above code to insert a function into a cell if another cell changes in value, though I cannot get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, just make sure you place it in the correct worksheet you want it to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Range("D10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(, -2).Formula = "=Now()" '<-- place the formula 2 columns to the left of the cell you just modified
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True ' <-- restore original setting

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a little add-in: with such a If-End If block it'd be logically cleaner to put bothApplication.EnableEvents statements inside it